# Gutenberg WooCommerce Product Sort

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks

I want to sort the woocommerce product order by price which as I understand is not by default possible. How can I set the sorting? It shows "invalid orderby params" if I pass 'price' to it.

[image]

```
attributes: {
    numProducts: {
        type: "number",
        default: 5,
    },
    itemsPerRow: {
        type: "string",
        default: "3",
    },
    sortOrder: {
        type: "string",
        default: "asc",
    },
    sortType: {
        type: "string",
        default: "price",
    },
}
```

```
withSelect((select, props) => {
    const { sortOrder, numProducts, itemsPerRow } = props.attributes;

    return {
        products: select("core").getEntityRecords("postType", "product", {
            per_page: numProducts,
            orderby: "price", // it shows price is not a valid params
            order: sortOrder,
            items_per_row: itemsPerRow,
            _embed: true,
            image: true,
        }),
    };
})
```